# Deja Dup backup no longer working

Tags: sd-card, deja-dup

I have been backing up my ~/home directory onto a 128GB SD card using Deja Dup for years now. I have directories on the card for each release of Ubuntu and when the card is full I delete a directory.  I recently upgraded to 23.10 though I don't know if this has anything to do with the problem, I mention it just in case.

Today after attempting an automatic backup Deja Dup informed me the sd card was full. So I deleted some old files and tried to backup manually. The app now said the media need 156GB of space to proceed. I checked the SD card and it was now empty. I tried with another SD card, though I only had a 32GB available. Deja Dup again said that it required at least 156GB.

What is happening here? My ~/home directory is as it always has been, there are no new big files in it, the 128GB SD card has been ok for years so why is it no longer big enough? I have checked the card and it is pefectly readable and writable